# Group capturing a semicolon delimited string is missing the last group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

My input string is

```
String input=" 4313 :F:7222;scott miles:F:7639;Henry Gile:G:3721";
```

It's a string with semicolon delimiter. It can contain any number of values delimited by semicolon

I want to use Group capture feature in java and capture the below values (i.e : delimited)

```
         4313 :F:7222
         scott miles:F:7639
         Henry Gile:G:3721
```

I know I can use split function under Spring class but for some reason I want to use group capture here.

I tried

```
Matcher myMatcher = Pattern.compile("(.*?);").matcher(input);
while (myMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group is " + myMatcher.group());
}
```

output is

```
group is  4313 :F:7222;
group is scott miles:F:7639;
```

but expected output is

```
group is  4313 :F:7222
group is scott miles:F:7639
group is Henry Gile:G:3721
```

I am not getting how to capture the last value after last semicolon and also I want to get rid of semicolon as I mentioned in expected outcome.

Comment: Try adding a `?` after the `;`. It should capture the last group too.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea no no no, don't add a `?` after the `;`. You'll get completely distorted matches! If you want to know what I mean by this, check out this regex demo: http://regex101.com/r/jV6fD4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the regex:

```
([^;]+)
```

This should get all the groups you require.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/wO3dL6).

Comment: I got the explanation  from the link you mentioned. but i think ([^;]*) is as good as ([^;]+) in my case right?

Comment: @emilly Yup. I usually try using what's "safer" because you'll also get empty strings in your results.

Comment: I think what you mean is + will search one or more occurence of any character except semicolumn while * will search 0 or more occurence(thats why * will include empty spaces also). Is that correct?

Comment: Please see if my last comment makes sense to you

Comment: @emilly Ooops, I didn't get any notification of your last comment. But yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

You're seeking for group that finishes with semicolumn. That's why your regex mathes just two groups instead of 3 ones.
You can use approach that seeking for group that starts with each symbol that is not a semicolumn.

```
([^;]+)
```

or you can use semicolumn character or end of line character while parsing input string:

```
(.+?)(;|$)
```

Both of these approaches give an expected result.

P.S. For second one you need to get 1st group for expected result:

```
System.out.println("group is " + myMatcher.group(1));
```

Comment: Actually it matches each group one by one that should not contain semicolumn. If semicolumn is found (it's like a separator in our case), that means we got new group if there is at least one symbols after semicolumn.

Comment: Nope.if to use ([^;]*) the output will be six groups: group is 4313 :F:7222
group is 
group is scott miles:F:7639
group is 
group is Henry Gile:G:3721
group is 
* is greedy operator, it searches for semicolumn and when it finds we have a new empty group for semicolumn - that's why we have 6 groups.